# Generate XSD from WSDL in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink

Is there a way to generate XSD from a WSDL file in eclipse IDE.It's a project requirement to generate the XSD from the WSDL and then auto generate all the java classes using jaxb. I also use eclipselink in my project. Can eclipselink be used for this task?

Comment: Why don't you generate Java classes straight from WSDL? What is the purpose of that extra XSD step?

Comment: As I have mentioned it is a project requirement. I am aware that that the java classes can be directly generated from the wsdl using jaxb2-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Select `File`/`New`/`Other...`/`JAXB`/`JAXB Classes from Schema`.

When specifying schema options there is an option "Source is a WSDL, use its schema", or something like that...

### EDIT

To tell you the truth, i never used this feature. I generated classes from normal Schema files, but noticed the aforementioned option.

Comment: Can you let me know which version of eclipse you are using. Currently I have Eclipse Neon but the schema selection window only allows xsd files to be browsed.

Comment: Neon.2 (4.6.2) for JavaEE

Comment: Also used Mars.3 and some older versions, too

Comment: I tried using Neon.2 (4.6.2) for JavaEE and Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) as well but still it doesn't allow to select wsdl. can you please attach a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

I could generate the xsd files from the WSDL using SOAP UI to resolve this.It was much easier.